# How to multiply a value, returned by a shortcode in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

So I can't get my head around this. I am basically using a plugin that has the following shortcode

Example: [valueABC] which is equal to 40.

Now I want to multiply the value by 2, so the output with be 40*2 = 80 on the frontend. But can't figure out how to do it without hard coding it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function vx_summation(){
    $vxtr=10;
    return $vxtr;
}

add_shortcode('summation_shortcode','vx_summation');


function vx_preview_summation(){
    $vxtr = do_shortcode('[summation_shortcode]');
    return $vxtr*3;
}

add_shortcode('preview_summation_shortcode','vx_preview_summation');

[preview_summation_shortcode]
```

OR you can Follow this Documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/